# RxJava Thread.sleep in another thread

Tags: android, rx-java

How with use `RxJava` update `UI` every one second in Android?
I'm trying to do something like this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i <10 ; i++) { //test
               rx.Observable.just(getSleep())
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe(v->updateTime());//update textView
        }

    private <T> int getSleep() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

But Thread.sleep() doing in ui thread. 
What I to do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS) //emits item every second
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) //switches thread from computation (interval's default) to UI
            .subscribe(i -> updateUI()); //update your textView
```

Comment: remember to unsubscribe this `onPause()` and resubscribe `onResume()`

Answer (score 1):

```
rx.Observable.just(getSleep())
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(v->updateTime());//update textView
```

it's like

```
int stuff = getSleep();
rx.Observable.just(stuff)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(v->updateTime());//update textView
```

If your code is running in the UI Thread then `getSleep()` will be executed in the UI Thread. You'll have to defer your call (using `fromCallable` for example).

```
     rx.Observable.fromCallable(() -> getSleep())
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(v->updateTime());//update textView
```

Comment: I'm trying to do something like a stopwatch. 
`fromCallable` not corrected the situation as needed(